# syntax error in update statement run-time error 3144

Tags: vba, ms-access

I got  syntax error in update statement.Run-time error: 3144 
 I use the following code

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE product " & _
    " SET [product name] = '" & Me.txtName & "'" & _
    ", [cost of product] = " & Me.txtCost & "" & _
    ", [weight] = " & Me.txtWeight & "" & _
    ", [group] = '" & Me.CmbGroup & "'" & _
    ", [group ID] = '" & Me.txtGroupID & "'" & _
    ", [Ordered] = " & Me.txtOrdered & "" & _
    " WHERE [roduct name] = " & Me.txtName.Tag & ""
```

What can be the problem? 
If it makes sense, then Me.txtCost , Me.txtWeight and me.txtOrdered are number

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This looks wrong: `WHERE [roduct name]`  Should that be `[product name]` instead? Can Me.txtCost, Me.txtWeight, Me.txtOrdered, or Me.txtName.Tag be Null?

Comment: Use a string variable, *strUpdate*, to hold your `UPDATE` statement.  Then use `Debug.Print strUpdate` to see what you're asking the db engine to execute.  And you can execute it with `CurrentDb.Execute strUpdate`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick help! That was the problem, the mistyping... annoying.. However I have one more issue with it, is there a code to ignore if you don't put data in one field? As this code is only works if you fill up the all fields, otherwise I got an error. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems that I see:

1. Typo in `WHERE [roduct name]` (should be `WHERE [product name]`)
2. Missing quotes around `Me.txtName.Tag` at the end of the statement

Try this instead:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE product " & _
    " SET [product name] = '" & Me.txtName & "'" & _
    ", [cost of product] = " & Me.txtCost & "" & _
    ", [weight] = " & Me.txtWeight & "" & _
    ", [group] = '" & Me.CmbGroup & "'" & _
    ", [group ID] = '" & Me.txtGroupID & "'" & _
    ", [Ordered] = " & Me.txtOrdered & "" & _
    " WHERE [product name] = '" & Me.txtName.Tag & "'"
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick help! That was the problem, the mistyping... annoying.. However I have one more issue with it, is there a code to ignore if you don't put data in one field? As this code is only works if you fill up the all fields, otherwise I got an error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To future readers of this post, reconsider interpolating or concatenating VBA values into a dynamic SQL query. Consider [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx) with MS Access' [QueryDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194892.aspx). This will avoid mistyping, misquoting, and unreadable, and unmaintainable code.

**SQL** *(save as an MS Access stored query only once)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [txtName_PARAM] TEXT, [txtCost_PARAM] DOUBLE,
           [txtWeight_PARAM] DOUBLE, [CmbGroup_PARAM] TEXT,
           [txtGroupID_PARAM] TEXT, [txtOrdered_PARAM] LONG,
           [txtName_Tag_PARAM] TEXT;
UPDATE product 
SET [product name] = [txtName_PARAM],
    [cost of product] = [txtCost_PARAM],
    [weight] = [txtWeight_PARAM],
    [group] = [CmbGroup_PARAM],
    [group ID] = [txtGroupID_PARAM],
    [Ordered] = [txtOrdered_PARAM],
    WHERE [product name] = [txtName_Tag_PARAM];
```

**VBA** *(dynamically bind values to parameter placeholders)*

```vb
Dim qdef as QueryDef

Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

qdef![txtName_PARAM] = Me.txtName
qdef![txtCost_PARAM] = Me.txtCost
qdef![txtWeight_PARAM] = Me.txtWeight
qdef![CmbGroup_PARAM] = Me.CmbGroup
qdef![txtGroupID_PARAM] = Me.txtGroupID 
qdef![txtOrdered_PARAM] =  Me.txtOrdered
qdef![txtName_Tag_PARAM] = Me.txtName.Tag 

qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

Set qdef = Nothing
```